# alloc + init with synthesized property - does it cause retain count to increase by two?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties, retain

I've seeen the following snippet quite a bit:

In the header:

```
SomeClass *bla;
@property(nonatomic,retain) SomeClass *bla;
```

In the implementation file:

```
@synthesize bla;
```

and then

```
self.bla = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

I think that this assignment puts the retain count for 'bla' up by two; once through the alloc/init call, then through the retain that we asked to happen through the synthesized property setter.

As a result, I normally declare my properties like this:

In the header:

```
SomeClass *_bla; // note the underscore
@property(nonatomic,retain) SomeClass *bla;
```

In the implementation file:

```
@synthesize bla = _bla;
```

and then

```
_bla = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

Provided my initial assumption is correct - I'd be interested to hear whether there is 'right' way to do this, i.e. the declaration, initialisation and memory management of properties?

Comment: First, welcome to Stack Overflow.  One of the things that's important to do on Stack is to accept answers that work for you.  It's important for the answerers, and for your own reputation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are right - using the synthesized setter of a `retain` property would increase the ref-count on an instance you already own (as `alloc` implies ownership).

Just go with the second form you mentioned in your initializers:

```
_bla = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

... and remember to fix the retain count otherwise, e.g.:

```
self.bla = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 9):

> I think that this assignment puts the retain count for 'bla' up by two;

True.

> I'd be interested to hear whether there is 'right' way to do this

Your last piece of code is the right way, but the leading underscore is not recommended. The property and the ivar can share the same name. Just

```
@interface Foo : Bar {
  SomeClass* bla;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeClass* bla;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bla;
-(id)init {
   ...
   bla = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
   ...
}
-(void)dealloc {
  [bla release];
  ...
  [super dealloc];
}
```

is enough.

---

Some people may use

```
SomeClass* foo = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
self.bla = foo;
[foo release];
```

or

```
self.bla = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

in the `-init` method, but I **strongly discourage** it, as this calls unnecessarily many methods, [and you cannot guarantee the behavior of the setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150494/objective-c-dot-syntax-and-init/3150906#3150906).

Comment: Wao - my first post on stackoverflow, and two answers within 5 minutes. Thank you both!

Comment: The two patterns you strongly discourage are perfectly acceptable and normal in most cases.  The answer you linked to relates **only** to use of accessors to set objects in the `init` and `dealloc` methods.  Everywhere else, the Apple recommendation is always to use the accessors to access instance variables.

Comment: JeremyP is right, and for that reason this shouldn't be considered a correct answer.

Comment: Should be severely voted down for recommending instance variables without a leading underscore. Having the same identifier for the property and the instance variable will inevitably lead to confusion and serious bugs. Like incorrect retain counts when assigning to bla instead of self.bla by accident, observers not being triggered and so on.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the core problem here is a misunderstanding of object ownership semantics in Cocoa.  For every `init`, `copy` or `retain` called on an object a call to `release` or `autorelease` must be made.  What's happening here is that the call to `init` doesn't have a matching call to `release` or `autorelease`.

I think what's confusing here is that the dot-notation for property assignment is syntactic sugar for a method call.  So it looks like it's just an assignment when in actuality it's a call to a property setter.

```
self.bla = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

is not the same thing as:

```
bla = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

The former translates into:

```
[self setBla: [[SomeClass] alloc] init]];
```

while the latter is literally an assignment.

To fix your issue all you really need to do is ensure that the code that calls `init` calls `autorelease` so that the retain count will be decremented after the `retain` call by the setter.

Answer (score -3):

There is no double count. The setter created by by synthesize does a release before doing a retain. See Stanford class on objective c class 3 as referenced on the apple website. It is also worth noting that in case of iboutlets the alloc init is not needed as it is performed through loading of the xib file

Comment: Voted down for being wrong. [[xxx alloc] init] returns an object with a retain count of 1, which must be counteracted at some point. If you store the result in a retained property, then immediately set the retained property to nil, you've got a memory leak.