# How to write a custom initializer that prevents viewDidLoad being called?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, initialization, ios5

I would like to build a custom init method for a `UIViewController`, but after digging around on the Internet and specifically in SO I am confused about designated initializers.

I have a subclass of an `UIViewController` with these two initializers:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if ( self ) {

  }
  return self;
}

- (id) initWithFilename:(NSString *)aFilename {
  self = [self initWithNibName:@"WallpaperDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
  if ( self ) { 
    self.filename = aFilename;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Then I have a `viewDidLoad` method that customizes the view according to the `filename` property:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Create a UIImageView to display the wallpaper
  self.wallpaper = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.filename]];
  // ...
}
```

In another `UIViewController` I make the following call:

```
WallpaperDetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[WallpaperDetailsViewController alloc] initWithFilename:@"foobar.png"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

The result is that `viewDidLoad` is being called as a consequence of `[self initWithNibName:]`, which does not initialize the `UIImageView` because `self.filename` is null.

According to other SO questions and answers, that should be the expected behavior. I am not sure about this because of my own experience in other projects prior to iOS 5. My question is:

How can I ensure that `viewDidLoad:` is call after `initWithFilename:` and not between `initWithFilename:` and `initWithNibNameOrNil:bundle:`?

If that's not possible, how can I implement an initializer method that receives custom data to create and customize the view?

Thanks!

Comment: How is filename defined? A declared property or a custom accessory?

Comment: `filename` is defined like `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *filename;` in `@interface` declaration of `WallpaperDetailsViewController`

Comment: something is happening in your init code that is causing the view to get loaded. set a break point in view did load and see why it is getting called early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.

`WallpaperDetailsViewController` does not inherit directly from `UIViewController`, but from another custom `UIViewController` I have implemented.

And what was the problem? That I have initialized a subview in the parent's `initWithNibName` method, instead of following the lazy-load technique and doing it in `viewDidLoad`. When `WallpaperDetailsViewController` was calling its parent initializer it got messy and cause `viewDidLoad` not to behave properly.

The solution? I moved every subview initialization in the parent class to its `viewDidLoad` method, and keep my original implementation of `WallpaperDetailsViewController` intact. Now everything is working as expected

Thanks to @Josh Caswell and @logancautrell

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I guess my answer was kind of an aside, but it was clear that the solution lay in code other than what you had posted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that empty implementation of `initWithNibName:bundle:`. Furthermore, it looks like your class here is establishing its designated initializer to be `initWithFilename:` If that's true, `initWithFilename:` should be calling the superclass's D.I.:

```
- (id) initWithFilename:(NSString *)aFilename {
  // Call super's designated initializer
  self = [super initWithNibName:@"WallpaperDetailsViewController" 
                         bundle:nil];
  if ( self ) { 
    self.filename = aFilename;
  }
  return self;
}
```

The rule is that all initializers *within* a class should call the class's D.I., and the D.I. should itself call the superclass's D.I.

It's not completely clear from what you've posted why `loadView:` is being called before your initializer has completed. Logancautrell's comment suggesting setting breakpoints in the view loading methods is good.

Comment: Actually I thought that, but it doesn't work for me in this case. That's why I've hitting my head against a wall before asking here.

Comment: The `UIImageView` is not created properly, because `viewDidLoad` is called just before setting `self.filename = aFilename`.

Comment: Well, I guess that makes sense, since in this case `[super initWithNibName:@"..." bundle:nil];]` is exactly equivalent to calling that on `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a custom setter for the filename property that initializes the UIImage every time the filename is set?

Or, alternately, set the UIImage from the filename property in viewWillAppear: instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Of course that's an alternative solution, but I would like to understand the behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not recommended that you use dot syntax within your initializer.  See the following for some good discussion:

[Objective-C Dot Syntax and Init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150494/objective-c-dot-syntax-and-init)

Second, what you could do is assign the image in your initializer as well.  So you could do something along the lines of

```
- (id) initWithFilename:(NSString *)aFilename {
   self = [self initWithNibName:@"WallpaperDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
   if ( self ) { 
      filename = [aFilename retain];
      wallpaper = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:aFileName]];
   }
   return self;
}
```

This will allow you to get everything setup and in good shape before viewDidLoad is called.

Good Luck!

Comment: There's no need for creating the image view in the view controller's intializer method. In fact, that could cause trouble should the VC receive a memory warning. Best to stick to the lazy-loading paradigm and only allocate it when needed, in `loadView:` or `viewDidLoad:`